# Ubuntu not booting and can't mount system partition from live USB (partition in use)

Tags: boot, mount, data-corruption

I have a dual boot installation with Ubuntu 20.04 that got somehow corrupted to the point that it won't boot anymore.
I have all my data backed up so in the worst case I can just reinstall, but I'd like to at least scavenge some config files before I do it.

The problem is that when I boot with a live Ubuntu USB, I cannot access the system and home partitions. For example:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/linsys

mount: /mnt/linsys: /dev/nvme0n1p2 already mounted or mount point busy.
```

Similarly if I try to check the filesystem it will instead complain that the partition is in use:

```
$ sudo e2fsck '/dev/nvme0n1p2'

e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

How can I access this partition again?

Comment: Do you have an open /swapfile there? Use `swapon --show` to see.

Comment: @heynema there's no open swapfile

Comment: Strange. I've put my normal `fsck` into an answer, and you may be doing the same thing already, but give it a try. Report back.

Comment: Wouldn't let me do it. I ended up deleting the partitons *through Windows* and reinstalling

Comment: Sounds like it was really corrupted. Have you installed a Windows driver that allows you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions?